# Raspberry Pi 4 does not boot and only shows red LED

Tags: pi-4

I bought a raspberry pi 4 and a 32gb sd card, i followed the steps on loading the image on the sd card, and the Raspberry pi will only show the red light. How can i fix this?

Comment: what steps did you follow for loading the image onto the SD card?

Comment: you either a) flashed the SD card wrong; b) have a sd card that doesn't work with raspberry pi (unlikely); c) have a faulty sdcard slot on the pi; or d) have a faulty raspberry pi - you'll need to do some sleuthing to find out which